# Detect silence while playing sound

Tags: asterisk

I am developing an java-asterisk application that is calling subscribers to deliver messages. At some moments during the call, I need to monitor whether the subscriber is talking or is silent. I need to monitor that for a fairly long time (1-3 seconds) but don't want to interrupt the flow of the outgoing message.
The way I am doing it now is as below

```
streamFile(*file A*);
exec("WaitForSilence","300,1,1");
waitStatus=getVariable("WAITSTATUS");
streamFile(*file B*);
```

This works fine but it is only a 300ms detect and a 1s timeout, so from the subscriber point of view the silence between file A and file B is almost unnoticeable. But if I want to listen for longer (say 3 seconds for example) then the subscriber's experience will be ruined.

What I would need is a function similar to "WaitForSilence" but that:

- runs in parallel to the script;
- delivers its outcome in a variable channel with a name that I define (as there might be several calls to the function, and I need to get all the results)

I've been looking for more than aweek now and couldn't find a way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code  you provided will do wait, after that will do playback.

There are no way do that simple in one application.

Posible ways:

1) create c/c++ application(asterisk guru skill required) for that.

2) create enother channel, mix it with ChanSpy and in that channel do silence detect. Complexity - expert in asterisk.

Both are not so short(more then 2-3 screens of code), so can't be described in this site.

You can also try use Background application, but i am afraid it will not work too.

Comment: Doesn't really solve my issue but at least now it's clear what is feasible and what is not. I will need to look for another route to tackle my initial issue.